# Save big webgl texture to disk

Tags: save, textures, disk, webgl

I did a webgl shader that generate a procedural texture of about 8k * 4k. I need to save this texture to disk. I was wondering if there is some facility to do that. I know it would be possible to write a function that retrieve the texture by block and rebuild it in a 2d canvas to recontruct it, but before doing that I would like to be sure there is not other way.

Anyone ?

Answer (score 1):

Check the [File API](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/) and the [File API Writer](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/) for HTML5, you must also keep in mind that your canvas must be untainted (read: no cross-origin images rendered) to read the pixels from it.

With the File API you must read the pixels and write them as a blob directly.

Comment: The problem is not really writing the file to disk but to extract the big texture into an image/canvas that would do the job.

Comment: You would use an ArrayBuffer with readPixels, and then you can do whatever you want with it (ArrayBuffer can give you direct array access to the pixels with a DataView, or save it to a file with BlobBuilder).